# Delete row on remove click React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have following code where i am adding dynamic row and column. I want to delete row which on click.

But, getting difficulty figure it out.

```
class TableCells extends Component {

  onDeleteEvent = event => {
    // Delete row 
  };

  render() {

      var numberOfRow = this.props.numberOfRow; // user input
      var numberOfColumn = this.props.numberOfColumn; // user input

      var rows = Array.from({length: numberOfRow}).map((_, rowIdx) => (

        <tr key={rowIdx}>{
          Array.from({length: numberOfColumn}).map((_, colIdx) => (
            <EditableCell key={colIdx}/>
          ))
        }

        <td>
          <input type="button" onClick={this.onDeleteEvent} value="X" />
        </td>
        </tr>
      ))

      return (<tbody>{rows}</tbody>);
  }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this sandbox. 
A little simplified, but works for you.
https://codesandbox.io/s/9l9wnonyp

Basically, move your object in the state, and when you delete the item send his ID as parameter, and just set the new state, and it will rerender.

```
<input
   type="button"
   onClick={() => this.onDeleteEvent(rowIdx)}
   value="X"
/>
```

And onDeleteFunction:

```
onDeleteEvent = id => {
    // Delete row
    let rows = this.state.rows;
    rows.splice(id, 1);

    this.setState({
      rows
    });
  };
```

For any other question just comment here, and I will help you :)

Comment: Cool. Nice solution but, still some issue while deleting some row same as your https://codesandbox.io/s/xp259q9wvq. Trying to fix that.

Comment: What problem? I create the sandbox as a direction where you have to go :) you can adjust it as you want. And pls mark it as ok, if helped you, maybe other people will need the same stuff...

Comment: Problem is if delete first and then try to delete last it won't allow, again you delete first and try to delete any of last 2 won't allowed, again first then last 3 and so....
Yes. will mark correct.

Comment: I got the issue, I delete the `id` from the array, but then the `rowIdx` is not updated, and he tries to delete the last position which doesn't exist after the first delete. If you need I can update the answer

Comment: Sandbox link updated, but you should move the `tr` in a new component maybe, but this is your choise.

Answer (score 1):

The right way to do this would be to:

```
class TableCells extends Component {

  render() {
      const onDeleteEvent = (id) => () => this.props.onDeleteEvent(id);
      var numberOfRow = this.props.numberOfRow; // user input
      var numberOfColumn = this.props.numberOfColumn; // user input

      var rows = Array.from({length: numberOfRow}).map((_, rowIdx) => (

        <tr key={rowIdx}>{
          Array.from({length: numberOfColumn}).map((_, colIdx) => (
            <EditableCell key={colIdx}/>
          ))
        }

        <td>
          <input type="button" onClick={onDeleteEvent(colIdx)} value="X" />
        </td>
        </tr>
      ))

      return (<tbody>{rows}</tbody>);
  }
}
```

And wherever you use `TableCells`and presumably store the number of rows you are passing as a prop to `TableCells`, you would have a function that reduces the number of rows passed, thus affecting the `numberOfRow` prop.

I'm guessing you are using `TableCells` something like this:

```
<TableCells numberOfRow={this.state.numberOfRow} numberOfColumn={this.state.numberOfColumn} />
```

You should change it like this:

```
<TableCells
    numberOfRow={this.state.numberOfRow} 
    numberOfColumn={this.state.numberOfColumn} 
    onDeleteEvent={(idOfColumnToDelete) => {//Modify state here...})}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one

```
class TableCells extends Component {
  state = {
    numRows = this.props.numberOfRow  // I know it is considered as an antipattern :) But in this case that's ok!!!
  }

  onDeleteEvent = () => {
    // also you should add the check if it's not zero :)
    this.setState({ numRows: this.state.numRows - 1 });
  };

  render() {

      const { numberOfColumn } = this.props; // user input
      const { numRows } = this.state;

      const rows = Array.from({length: numRows }).map((_, rowIdx) => (

        <tr key={rowIdx}>
          {
            Array.from({length: numberOfColumn}).map((_, colIdx) => (
              <EditableCell key={colIdx}/>
            ))
          }

          <td>
            <input type="button" onClick={this.onDeleteEvent} value="X" />
          </td>
        </tr>
      ));

      return (<tbody>{rows}</tbody>);
  }
}
```

Comment: The problem with the answer is the question supposes the user receives the number of rows as a prop, so presumably it would like that state to remain in a component above in the hierarchy, as the prop is not called "initialNumberOfRow" for example

Comment: Gotcha, then the author should use this link https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html :)

Comment: It stops my row and column display functionality

Answer (score 0):

```
  class TableCells extends Component {
    constructor () {
    super()
    this.state = {
      numberOfRow: Array.from({length: this.props.numberOfRow}),
      numberOfColumn: Array.from({length: this.props.numberOfColumn})
    }
  }
  onDeleteEvent (index) {
    this.state.numberOfRow.splice(index, 1)
  };

  render () {
    var rows = this.state.numberOfRow.map((elem, index) => (<tr>
      {this.state.numberOfColumn.map((_, colIdx) => {<EditableCell key={colIdx}/>})}
      <td>
        <input type='button' onClick={() => this.onDeleteEvent(index)} value='X' />
      </td>
    </tr>))
    return (
      <tbody>{rows}</tbody>
    )
  }
}
```